# Нужно ли выделить запятыми "в числе прочего"?

Tags: пунктуация

Основными задачами системы школьного образования в числе прочего являются: выявление и оценка успеваемости.
В числе прочего сотрудник контролирует соблюдение графика работ.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Оборот «в числе прочего» близок по значение к сочетанию «среди прочего», то есть обособляется **по правилам для обстоятельственных оборотов**, выраженных падежными формами существительных  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114

Такое обособление является **факультативным** и зависит от различных факторов  (распространенность оборота и предложения, позиция в предложении и др.). Поэтому в каждом случае решение **может быть разным.**

Оборот довольно **компактный**, он без труда вписывается в структуру предложения, поэтому чаще  **не обособляется**. В то же время  варианты с обособлением тоже встречаются.

2. В данном случае можно предложить такие решения:

*Основными задачами системы школьного образования, **в числе прочего**, являются: выявление и оценка успеваемости.*

***В числе прочего** сотрудник контролирует соблюдение графика работ.*

3. Примеры

Но на Западе все крупные промышленные проекты проходят, **в числе прочего**, независимую общественную экологическую экспертизу. [Николай Кононов, 2003]

**В числе прочего** он опрокинул локтем со стола сумку Одарки, из которой выпала книга Кастанеды, а из той вылетели две фотографии. [Сергей Шикера, 2014]

**В числе прочего** в тайнике был крупнокалиберный снаряд. [Юлия Гутова, 2012]

**В числе прочего** я говорил, что всякая власть является насилием над людьми… [Михаил Булгаков, Мастер и Маргарита]

Answer (score 3):

**Нет**.

Словосочетание "в числе прочего" довольно часто встречается как в устной, так и в письменной речи, вследствие чего его можно назвать устойчивым выражением.

В [Справочном бюро русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B2+%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE) на эту тему есть три вопроса. На каждый из них ответ четкий: "Нет, не нужно", "Нет, не выделяется".

Таким образом, это выражение не обособляется запятыми, а если и так, то стоит говорить либо об авторской пунктуации, либо о каком-то особом случае.

> В речи же это выражение часто обособляется небольшими паузами.